# abcde - inconsistent/unexpected track numbers

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mp3, ogg, abcde

**Question**: How can I achieve my expected result of tracks that are numbered with sequential `{DiscNumber}{TrackNumber} - Artist - Album.mp3`?

**Background**: 
When using abcde to rip a set of audiobook CDs, the tracks for a given disc, for example disc 1 of a multidisc set, are numbered as below

**Actual** files created for Disc 1

```
65 - Artist - Album.mp3
66 - Artist - Album.mp3
67 - Artist - Album.mp3
68 - Artist - Album.mp3
n  - Artist - Album.mp3
```

**Actual** files created for Disc 2

```
 99 - Artist - Album.mp3
100 - Artist - Album.mp3
101 - Artist - Album.mp3
102 - Artist - Album.mp3
 n  - Artist - Album.mp3
```

**Expected** files for Disc 1

```
0101 - Artist - Album.mp3
0102 - Artist - Album.mp3
0103 - Artist - Album.mp3
0104 - Artist - Album.mp3
```

**Expected** files for Disc 2

```
0201 - Artist - Album.mp3
0202 - Artist - Album.mp3
0203 - Artist - Album.mp3
0204 - Artist - Album.mp3
```

I believe my configuration should create track names numbered like my "Expected files" above.  I suspect that some online metadata (maybe from CDDB or musicbrainz), is causing them to be named with a different numeric range, even though I've explicitly named the tracks in the .cddb entry.

**The command** I'm using to invoke abcde: `abcde -c ./.abcde.audiobook.conf -d /dev/sr0 -W 01 -p`

[my default abcde conf file - .abcde.conf](http://pasted.co/da9172df)

[my override abcde conf file - .abcde.audiobook.conf](http://pasted.co/8f2d4162)

Things to note...

1. I'm using the `-W ##` to prefix the filenames with disc `01, 02, ... n`
2. I'm also using -p to pad tracks, which, in my experience, does not work
3. Given #2, I manually pad tracks 0-9 with my editor, when the CDDB entry is displayed for me.

Comment: I've used abcde to rip multi-disc audiobook sets many times in the past and have never seen this behavior.  I've tried removing the <TAG> action from my abcde.conf as well as the CDDB action.. nothing seems to help the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @KamilMaciorowski.  Hopefully the question is now clear.